# How to disable autocommit in Eclipse Database Tools for Oracle?

Tags: eclipse, oracle, database-connection, driver, eclipse-dtp

I use Eclipse DTP for database queries. The connection is set to `autocommit=true` by default. I would like to disable autocommit.

I read this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13095_01/oepe-website/db-tools/gettingStarted/files/gettingStarted.html

There is said, that I can use the additional property `autocommit=false` to disable autocommit. I added this property at "Driver Properties" -> "Optional", but it still connects with autocommit enabled.

- Why doesn't this work?
- How do I disable autocommit the right way?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I use Eclipse Helios and Oracle 11 R1 11.1.0.7.0 and the driver ojdbc6 for 11.1.0.7.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chose Window -> Preferences -> Data Management -> SQL Development -> SQL Editor -> SQL Files/Scrapbooks
and Set "Manual" for Connection Commit Mode

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to restart Eclipse to get your change to activate.

Comment: IMO this is more of a comment than an answer.